# Incorrect assignment from a QStringList to a char * array

Tags: qt, qstringlist

```
    //This is my partial code.
    
    const char *MyparamValuesTagliando[16] = {nullptr};
    QString RigaDaCaricare;
    QStringList ListaElementiRiga;
    
    const int Destinatario = 0;
    const int Presso = 1;
    const int Toponimo = 2;
    const int Comune = 3;
    const int Cap = 4;
    const int Provincia = 5;
    const int Civico = 6;
    const int RifPratica_NumSinistro = 7;
    const int Note = 8;
    
    //RigaDaCaricare is a line of a .txt file
    //Something like "pippo;pluto;paperino;minni"
    ListaElementiRiga = RigaDaCaricare.split(";");
    
    //Some of the following assignments are OKs (I find the string I'am expecting) others KOs (strange characters)
    MyparamValuesTagliando[2] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Destinatario).toStdString().c_str();
    MyparamValuesTagliando[3] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Toponimo).toStdString().c_str();
    MyparamValuesTagliando[4] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Civico).toStdString().c_str();
    MyparamValuesTagliando[5] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Comune).toStdString().c_str();
    MyparamValuesTagliando[6] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Provincia).toStdString().c_str();
    MyparamValuesTagliando[7] = ListaElementiRiga.at(Cap).toStdString().c_str();
```

Some of the preceding assignments (ListaElementiRiga -> MyparamValuesTagliando) are OKs (I find the string I'am expecting) others KOs (strange characters).

Can someone help me?
Tk.

Please note: split is ok (all elements in ListaElementiRiga are OKs), but only some elements in MyparamValuesTagliando are OKs, others KOs).

Comment: All of your `MyparamValuesTagliando[...] = ListaElementiRiga.at(...).toStdString().c_str();` statements store the result of a `c_str()` call against a temporary `std::string` and will, therefore, result in dangling pointers when those temporaries are destroyed.  So your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you for some obscure reason must use raw char pointers, you need to use `strdup()` (note: it's a POSIX function,, so if you need fully portable C++ code, you will need to write your own implementation, basically one line of code).

Comment: G.M. and hyde, thanks for your answers.
Since G.M.'s suggestion came first, I reasoned on his indication, I made the necessary changes and now everything seems to be working.
Thank you and greetings.